# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2 x^2 + 1} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \mathrm{d}x,\quad a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I struggling to find the trick one should use to compute this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2 x^2 + 1} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} \mathrm{d}x,\quad a \in \mathbb{R}$$

any idea?

I know that the result is 
$$\frac{\pi}{1 + |a|}$$

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: Why search for tricks when there are general methods for integrals of rational functions

Comment: Thank you Dylan, I was able to do it with partial fractions. Thanks Yuriy for the reminder too!

Comment: The result should be $\frac{\pi}{1 + |a|}$.

Comment: Note to partial fractions: since there are just even powers of x one can view the expression as $\frac{1}{(a^2u+1)(u+1)}$ which reduces number of constants to 2.

Answer (score 3):

Note that:
$$\frac{1}{a^2x^2+1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{a^2-1}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)$$
So, you can split the original integral into two simples.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can use residue.
Let:
$$f(z)=\frac1{a^2z^2+1}\frac1{z^2+1}\\
=\frac1{a^2}\frac1{z+\frac ia}\frac1{z-\frac ia}\frac1{z+i}\frac1{z-i}$$
We turn the integration into:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{f(z)dz}$$
Consider the integration limit above:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\int_{-n}^n{f(z)dz}+\int_0^\pi{f(ne^{i\theta})d\theta})\\
=2\pi i(\operatorname{Res}[f(\frac i{|a|})]+\operatorname{Res}[f(i)])\\
=2\pi i(\frac{i|a|}{2-2a^2}+\frac i{-2+2a^2})=\frac \pi{1+|a|}$$
As$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\pi{f(ne^{i\theta})d\theta}=0$$
The integral equals to$\frac \pi{1+|a|}$.